# How to find an index with maximum number of rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing an online course which has a problem like " Find the name of the state with maximum number of counties". The problem dataframe is the image below

[Problem Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkQ0E.png)

Now, I have given the dataframe two new index (hierarchical indexing) and after that the dataframe takes a new look like the image below

[Modified Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R6nH.png)

I have used this code to get the modified dataframe:

```
def answer_five():
    new_df = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50] 
    new_df = new_df.set_index(['STNAME', 'CTYNAME'])


    return  new_df

answer_five()
```

What I want to do now is to find the name of the state with most number of counties i.e to find the index with maximum number of rows. How Can I do that?

I know that using something like groupby() method this can be done but I'm not familiar with this method yet and so don't want to use it. Can anyone help? I have searched for this but failed. Sorry if the problem is rudimentary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about you try with `new_df.index.get_level_values(0).nunique()` ?

Comment: That's a naughty -13 question you found @jezrael

Comment: @CeliusStingher - You are right, changed dupes.

Comment: @CeliusStingher

Hi, thank you for your reply. I have tried earlier something like your suggestion ( except the nunique part). Now also tried your suggestion.but it seems that that doesn't answer my question actually. I want to find the name o the state having maximum number of counties but your suggestion gave me a value.

Comment: Oh, you are right. You can then use  `sort_values()` to order them from max to min and keep the first value :)

Comment: @jezrael

Hi, thank you for the reply. I have checked the above two links you provided. The first link is actually a different question ( from the same problem set). The second link provide the solution but not the way I want. I don't want to use groupby() method while the give link's solution use that. I wonder if there is any way without using groupby().

Comment: @Sourav_Hasan - I think without `groupby` is is problem, because need processing per groups

Comment: @CeliusStingher

Hey, I am a bit confused how to use sort_values() here to get the state with maximum counties, I have at first used    `new_df.index.get_level_values('STNAME')`

which gives me name of the state for every row. Now is there way to count how many times each unique state name is there and get them in a series or list? I think after that we can use 
    `sort_values() `. Pardon me if I sound naive..